Exporting an SVG from a webpage
I want to make a button to print export a generated barcode as an svg or as an png
HTML code:
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="put the code here">
    <svg class="hidden" id="barcode" onclick="window.print(this)" id="svgObject" width="100" height="100"></svg>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Generate</button>
    <input class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button" onclick="printDiv('print-content')" value="print"/>
</section>
<script src="jsBarcode.code128.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

js code:
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click" , function() {
    var text = document.querySelector("input").value;
    JsBarcode("#barcode", text);
    document.getElementById("barcode").classList.remove("hidden")
});
function printDiv(divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(barcode).outerHTML;
    w=window.open();
    w.document.write(printContents);
    w.print();
    w.close();
}

I am using this barcode generator: https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/
When I use this code, it prints it as a PDF not an SVG or any image format.

"print a generated barcode as an svg or as an png" I don't believe I've ever seen the save as image when printing from a browser.

Are you just trying to create barcode images? There's probably no need to use a browser to do this. JsBarcode can be used from Node and there's even a SVG example on the project's web page https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode or https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsbarcode

As commented the browser's print function won't give you any conversion options.
File downloads
Since you already have a SVG output, all you need to do is create a data URL or a object URL you can apply to a <a> href attribute. By adding a download attribute the link will open a file download dialogue.


const barcode = document.getElementById('barcode');
const btnPrint = document.getElementById('btnPrint');
const btnGenerate = document.getElementById('btnGenerate');

//init example
(async() => {
  generateCode()
})();


btnGenerate.addEventListener("click", () => {
  generateCode()
});

btnPrint.addEventListener("click", () => {
  printDiv()
});



async function generateCode() {
  let text = document.querySelector("input").value;
  JsBarcode("#barcode", text);
  document.getElementById("barcode").classList.remove("hidden")

  // generate SVG download
  // serialize SVG markup
  let markup = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(barcode)
  // create blob
  let blob = new Blob([markup], {
    type: 'image/svg+xml'
  });
  downloadSvg.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

  //generate png output
  let dataUrlPng = await svg2PngDataUrl(barcode)
  downloadPng.href = dataUrlPng
}


/**
 * svg to canvas
 */
async function svg2PngDataUrl(el, scale = 1, filter = "") {
  /**
   *  clone svg to add width and height
   * for better compatibility
   * without affecting the original svg
   */
  const svgEl = el.cloneNode(true);

  // get dimensions
  let {
    width,
    height
  } = el.getBBox();
  let w = el.viewBox.baseVal.width ?
    svgEl.viewBox.baseVal.width :
    el.width.baseVal.value ?
    el.width.baseVal.value :
    width;
  let h = el.viewBox.baseVal.height ?
    svgEl.viewBox.baseVal.height :
    el.height.baseVal.value ?
    el.height.baseVal.value :
    height;

  // apply scaling
  [w, h] = [w * scale, h * scale];

  // add width and height for firefox compatibility
  svgEl.setAttribute("width", w);
  svgEl.setAttribute("height", h);

  // create canvas
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;

  // create blob
  let svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgEl);
  let blob = new Blob([svgString], {
    type: "image/svg+xml"
  });
  let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  let tmpImg = new Image();
  tmpImg.src = blobURL;
  tmpImg.width = w;
  tmpImg.height = h;
  tmpImg.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

  await tmpImg.decode();
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

  // apply filter to enhance contrast
  if (filter) {
    ctx.filter = filter;
  }
  ctx.drawImage(tmpImg, 0, 0, w, h);

  //create img data URL
  let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
  return dataUrl;
}

function printDiv() {
  var printContents = barcode.outerHTML;
  w = window.open();
  w.document.write(printContents);
  w.print();
  w.close();
}
.btn {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0.3em;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: inherit;
  line-height: 1em;
}
<svg class="hidden" id="barcode" id="svgObject" width="100" height="100"></svg>
<p>
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="put the code here" value="123456">
</p>

<p>
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="btnGenerate">Generate</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="btnPrint">Print</button>
<a href="" class="btn" id="downloadSvg" download="barcode.svg">Download SVG</a>
<a href="" class="btn" id="downloadPng" download="barcode.png">Download PNG</a>
</p>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.6/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>



For a rasterized png file output you need to draw the SVG on a <canvas> element and create a data URL via canvas.toDataURL(). See also "Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser"
Downloads don't work in SO snippets. See also working codepen example
